# $\ker(T^n) \cap\operatorname{Im}(T^n) = 0_v $

Tags: linear-transformations

I was asked to show that if $T: V \rightarrow V$ is a linear transformation such that $\dim V < \infty $ then there exists $n$ such that $\ker(T^n) \cap \operatorname{Im}(T^n) = 0_V $.

I succeeded to prove that, but I was wondering whether there exists a minimal $n$ that makes that true.

Comment: If you can show integer $n\gt 0$ exists, you can show a minimal such positive integer exists.  Of course the claim is trivially true for $n=0$.

Comment: I meant that if there exists a specific minimal $n$ that I can find according to the transformation I get, that i can calculate not just prove that it exists.

Comment: Any calculation will depend on what you know about the linear transformation.  For example, if $T$ is known to be nonsingular, then the claim is true with $n=1$.  So I suggest your problem setup should outline everything you propose to be known about $T$.  Perhaps you know a matrix representation (wrt a finite basis for $V$) or you know something about the invariant subspaces of $T$.

Comment: as far as calculations go, what you want is to calculate $\text{rank}\big(T^k\big)$ for $k=1,2,...$ and stop as soon as  $\text{rank}\big(T^{k-1}\big) = \text{rank}\big(T^k\big)$

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\im}{\operatorname{Im}}\newcommand{\ker}{\operatorname{Ker}}$
Since $V$ is finite dimensional, two sequences of subspace of $V$
$$\im(T)\supset\im (T^2)\supset\im(T^3)\supset\cdots$$
$$\ker(T)\subset\ker(T^2)\subset\ker(T^3)\subset\cdots$$
stabilize. So for some large $n$, $\im(T^n) = \im(T^{n+1})=\cdots$ and $\ker(T^n) = \ker(T^{n+1})\cdots$. Let $v\in\ker(T^n)\cap\im(T^n)$. Then $T^n(v) = 0$ and $T^n(w) = v$ for some $w$. Hence, $T^{2n}(w) = 0\Rightarrow w\in\ker(T^{2n}) = \ker(T^n)\Rightarrow T^n(w) = 0 = v$.